# How to use route name of mounted application in link_to helper?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I can mount application in Mojolicious like this:

```
$r->under( '/as_user/:user_id' )->route('/')->detour( 'App' );
```

Also I know that mounted application `App` has `show_package` route.

**How to use this route name in `link_to` helper?**

Next example will render host application route instead of mounted:

```
%= link_to 'Slave App package' => 'show_package', { user_id => 7, id => 32 };
```

This will render link to: `/packages/32` but I want `/as_user/7/packages/32`